# How can I attach second database to my rds instance from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see there is option of uploading multiple files to s3 bucket. I have uploaded a second file to it and I want to see it as a different database. In future, I will replace the first one with this one. How can I achieve it?

currently, I have one optionsgroup, one bucket (with two files) and one rds instance

Also, I have taken database dump from plesk, it does not have a .bak extension, should I rename and add .bak before uploading to s3?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is confusing. What do you when you say that you want to see a file as a 'different database'? Do you mean that you would like to import the contents of the file into a table in the database? Also, why are you mentioning plesk in your question? Please Edit your question and provide more detail of what you are wanting to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein, I wanted the second file to restore as a new database in ssms. I have now found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to do it!

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database
@restore_db_name='database_name',
@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/bakup_file'
```

This was the final step that I did earlier for the first file and had forgotten all about it.

Now all I need to do is add a different backup_file name in above query.